# how to check data is either video or image in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, video

I am using intent for picking image or video from gallery in my android app.

i am using following code

```
String fileTypeString = "image/* video/*";
Intent selectFileIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    selectFileIntent.setType(fileTypeString);
startActivityForResult(selectFileIntent, UploadImageAsyncTask.MEDIA_PICKER);
```

Now how can i find that result is either image or video?

EDIT: UploadImageAsyncTask.MEDIA_PICKER is my request code i have generated elsewhere.

Comment: Try this way : MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(getContentResolver().getType(data.getData()))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call below method with the parameter of your filepath.

```
public String getMimeType(String filePath) {
        String type = null;
        String extension = getFileExtensionFromUrl(filePath);
        if (extension != null) {
            MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
            type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
        }
        return type;
}
```